# Bugs from creating a new class inherited from STL set

Tags: c++, stl

I am a newbie in C++ and trying to finish the C++ assignment.  In the code question, I cannot change anything in the main function but could add code outside the main function.

Here is the main:

```
int main()
{
    MySet<int> stInt;
    int a[100];


    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0;i < n; ++i )
        cin >> a[i];
    MySet<int> stInt(a,a+n);
    MyPrint(stInt.begin(),stInt.end());
    cout << endl;
    int s,e;
    cin >> s >> e; 
    pair<MySet<int>::iterator, MySet<int>::iterator> p;
    p  = stInt.FindInterval(s,e);
    if( p.first != p.second) 
    {
        MyPrint(p.first,p.second);
        cout << endl;
    }
    else
       cout << "Interval Not Found" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    MySet<double,greater<double> > stDouble;
    for( int i = 0;i < n; ++i)  
    {
         double d;
         cin >> d;
         stDouble.insert(d);
    }
    MyPrint(stDouble.begin(),stDouble.end());
    cout << endl;
    double w;
    cin >> w;
    cout << * stDouble.upper_bound(w) << endl;

 return 0;
 }
```

To get the correct answer, my thought is to create a new STL class named `MySet`, which is inherited from STL set, and it seems the `MyPrint()` function has some bugs.  I really have no idea what this is.

BTW, I compile the code in VS2010 Pro. The bug info is:

unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl MyPrint(class std::_Tree_const_iterator,class std::allocator,0> > >,class std::_Tree_const_iterator,class std::allocator,0> > >)" (?MyPrint@@YAXV?$_Tree_const_iterator@V?$_Tree_val@V?$_Tset_traits@NU?$less@N@std@@V?$allocator@N@2@$0A@@std@@@std@@@std@@0@Z) referenced in function _main

And my snippet is:

```
template<typename T, class Compare = less<T>, class Alloc = allocator<T> >
class MySet:public set<T>
{
private:
    T st[100];
public:
    MySet():set<T>() {}
    MySet(int *first, int *last)
    {
        int *idx = first;
        for(int i = 0; idx <= last; ++idx, ++i)
            st[i] = *idx;
    }

    pair<typename set<T>::iterator, typename set<T>::iterator>FindInterval(int lower,   int upper)
    {
        typename set<T>::iterator low, up;
        low = lower_bound(lower);
        up = upper_bound(upper);
        return (pair<typename set<T>::iterator, typename set<T>::iterator>(low, up));

    }
    void friend MyPrint(typename set<T>::iterator first_, typename set<T>::iterator last_);


};

template<typename T>
void MyPrint(typename MySet<T>::iterator first_, typename MySet<T>::iterator last_)
{
typename MySet<T>::iterator it = first_;
for(; it != last_; ++it)
    cout << *it << " ";
}
```

The `MyPrint()` function just prints all the elements in `MySet`.

I have asked all the people knowing C++ but it seems they cannot help me... And I am stuck for more than 3 days....

Thanks!

Yiru

Comment: This is a linker error. That means you are missing to tell the linker to include the library where that custom set is implemented.

Comment: Hi, thx for your advice. In fact I have added the <set> library...

Comment: It seems like all you need to do is implement: `void MyPrint(MySet<int>::const_iterator b, MySet<int>::const_iterator e)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program declares two functions - or rather, two families of functions - named `MyPrint`. First, there is a set of non-template `friend` functions, one for each instantiation of `MySet` template. Second, there is a set of instantiations of `MyPrint` template. But you only provide the actual implementation for the second set.

For `MyPrint` call in `main`, both sets are viable candidates, and other things equal, the compiler prefers non-template to a template. Then the linker discovers that the non-template lacks implementation.

There are two ways around it. You could either implement the non-template in-class, and drop the template:

```
template <typename T>
class MySet {
  friend void MyPrint(...) { ... }
};
```

Or you could befriend the template, and drop the non-template:

```
template <typename T>
void MyPrint(typename set<T>::iterator, typename set<T>::iterator);

template <typename T>
class MySet {
  friend void MyPrint<T>(typename set<T>::iterator, typename set<T>::iterator);
};

template <typename T>
void MyPrint(typename set<T>::iterator, typename set<T>::iterator)
{ ... }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with STL, the issue is with core language features. It would be easy to construct an example that hits the same problem while not using a single STL class.

Comment: Hi Igor, you are right! Now another problem hits me... My default is to use less<class T> to compare elements in MySet. But there is one line in main:MySet<double,greater<double> > stDouble. So stDouble should be permulated using greater<double>. But my main function seems to arrange stDouble still using less<double>... Do you know how to fix that? Thx so much!

Comment: `MySet` takes three template parameters, but only passes one of them along to `set`. The other two are never used.

Comment: I've added the second template parameter to the constructor, but it seems wrong. Here is my code: MySet():set<T>() {Pred pr = less<T>;}And the compiler says it's wrong:   
c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\coursera_cpp\quizes\quize.cpp(14) : while compiling class template member function 'MySet<T>::MySet(void)'
          with
          [
              T=int
          ]                     Any ideas? Thx!

Comment: You want `class MySet : public set<T, Compare, Alloc>`. That's assuming you want to derive from `std::set` in the first place. What is the ultimate goal of the exercise, if you don't mind me asking? Your `MySet` class doesn't make much sense to me.